# How to check if a member name (variable or function) exists in a class, with or without specifying type?

Tags: c++, class, templates, macros, member

This Q is an extension of:
[Templated check for the existence of a class member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/257288/514235)

Is there any utility which will help to find:

- If a member name exists inside a class or not? This member can be a
  variable or a method.
- Specifying the type of the member should be optional

Comment: If you don't specify the type, then it should not have overload.

Comment: This question is a duplicate, not an extension of the linked question. The linked question already contains answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/264088 which explain everything in great detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### C++03

```
#define HasMember(NAME) \
  template<class Class, typename Type = void> \
  struct HasMember_##NAME \
  { \
    typedef char (&yes)[2]; \
    template<unsigned long> struct exists; \
    template<typename V> static yes Check (exists<sizeof(static_cast<Type>(&V::NAME))>*); \
    template<typename> static char Check (...); \
    static const bool value = (sizeof(Check<Class>(0)) == sizeof(yes)); \
  }; \
  template<class Class> \
  struct HasMember_##NAME<Class, void> \
  { \
    typedef char (&yes)[2]; \
    template<unsigned long> struct exists; \
    template<typename V> static yes Check (exists<sizeof(&V::NAME)>*); \
    template<typename> static char Check (...); \
    static const bool value = (sizeof(Check<Class>(0)) == sizeof(yes)); \
  }
```

**Usage**: Simply invoke the macro with whatever member you want to find:

```
HasMember(Foo);  // Creates a SFINAE `class HasMember_Foo`
HasMember(i);    // Creates a SFINAE `class HasMember_i`
```

Now we can utilize `HasMember_X` to check `X` in ANY `class` as below:

```
#include<iostream>
struct S
{
  void Foo () const {}
//  void Foo () {}  // If uncommented then type should be mentioned in `HasMember_Foo`    
  int i;
};
int main ()
{
  std::cout << HasMember_Foo<S, void (S::*) () const>::value << "\n";
  std::cout << HasMember_Foo<S>::value << "\n";
  std::cout << HasMember_i<S, int (S::*)>::value << "\n";
  std::cout << HasMember_i<S>::value << "\n";
}
```

**Catches**:

1. In case of methods, if we don't mention the type then the `class`
   must not have overloaded methods. If it has then this trick fails. 
   i.e. even though the named member is present more than once, the result will be `false`.
2. If the member is part of base class, then this trick fails; e.g. if `B` is base of `S` & `void B::Bar ()` is present, then `HasMember_Bar<S, void (B::*)()>::value` or `HasMember_Bar<S, void (S::*)()>::value` or `HasMember_Bar<S>::value` will give `false`

Answer (score 12):

With [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) and [`std::experimental::disjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/disjunction) you could do this:

```
//check for a type member named foo
template <typename T>
using foo_type_t = typename T::foo;

//check for a non-type member named foo
template <typename T>
using foo_non_type_t = decltype(&T::foo);

template <typename T>
using has_foo = disjunction<is_detected<foo_type_t, T>,
                            is_detected<foo_non_type_t, T>>;
```

Then you would use `has_foo<my_class>::value` in whatever you want.

The above will work for more than just types and member functions, but you could easily constrain it by using traits like `std::is_member_function_pointer` and `std::is_member_object_pointer` if you like.

To supply your optional argument, you could use the `std::experimental::is_detected_exact` helper.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57f59f8aa2643f3d)

---

Note that if you take the implementations of the above traits from the pages I linked, you can use this with C++14. A minor change to the `disjunction` code will let you use it in C++11.

Comment: Note that if you take the implementations of the above traits from the pages @TartanLlama linked, MSVC 2013 has an internal compiler error on struct detector.

Comment: How will this behave if there are multiple methods with the same name (i.e. overloads)? I guess the question should be modified also to clarify whether overloads are interesting

Comment: @AaronMcDaid It'd fail if there are overloads. You can get around that by making a class with a `foo` member, and checking if some dummy class can inherit from both that class and the one being checked.

Answer (score 1):

For non-C++17:

Boost Type Traits library [has metafunctions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_detail_has_member_function.html) for both checking if member with given name present or more fine grained control by giving signature.

Following is a program using slightly modified [`HAS_MEMBER`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/convert/detail/has_member.hpp) macro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER(__trait_name__, __member_name__)                          \
                                                                                     \
    template <typename __boost_has_member_T__>                                       \
    class __trait_name__                                                             \
    {                                                                                \
        using check_type = ::std::remove_const_t<__boost_has_member_T__>;            \
        struct no_type {char x[2];};                                                 \
        using  yes_type = char;                                                      \
                                                                                     \
        struct  base { void __member_name__() {}};                                   \
        struct mixin : public base, public check_type {};                            \
                                                                                     \
        template <void (base::*)()> struct aux {};                                   \
                                                                                     \
        template <typename U> static no_type  test(aux<&U::__member_name__>*);       \
        template <typename U> static yes_type test(...);                             \
                                                                                     \
        public:                                                                      \
                                                                                     \
        static constexpr bool value = (sizeof(yes_type) == sizeof(test<mixin>(0)));  \
    }

struct foo
{
    int bar(){}
};

struct baz
{};

DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER(has_bar, bar);

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_bar<foo>::value << '\n' << has_bar<baz>::value;
}
```

As noted in linked page it uses the fact that if you inherit from two classes that have members with same name, attempts to use this name will become ambiguous.

Comment: How about the member with "type"?