# SFINAE to determine if a type has a potentially overloaded method

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-meta-programming

I was looking for an SFINAE solution to check at compile time if a type has a method. My goal is to check if a type is a valid ["duck type"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), but instead of a useless compile error, I want to use `static_assert` to provide an informative message.

I found [this question], which provides a fairly good answer to my problem, except it fails when the type provides overload to the method:

```
template<typename...> // parameter pack here
using void_t = void;

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_xxx : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_xxx<T, void_t<decltype(&T::xxx)>> :
  std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::xxx)>{};
```

This works fine with the following example, and differentiate method and member variable:

```
struct Foo { int xxx() {return 0;}; };
struct Foo2 {};
struct Foo3{ static double xxx;};
double Foo3::xxx = 42;

int main() {
   static_assert(has_xxx<Foo>::value, "");
   static_assert(!has_xxx<Foo2>::value, "");
   static_assert(!has_xxx<Foo3>::value, "");
}
```

[Original live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ece49409d3bd1e2)

The code fails if there is an overload:

```
struct Foo { int xxx() {return 0;}  void xxx(int){} };

int main() {
   static_assert(has_xxx<Foo>::value, "");
}
```

[Failing live demo with overloaded method](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45adf7ea6609a29c)

How can this code be improved to handle overloading?

Comment: Well, what're you trying to test? Just if the name `xxx` exists at all (why?), or if you can invoke `xxx` with some arguments (which ones?)?

Comment: I don't think if it's possible if you don't provide additional parameters if function is overloaded. But I would love to see an answer :)

Comment: Related or Duplicate: [How to check if a member name (variable or function) exists in a class, with or without specifying type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36079170/514235)

Comment: I think the question here, and the answers, might be more comprehensive that the question that @iammilind linked to. Maybe that should be marked as the dupe, keeping this question instead?

Comment: This question isn't duplicate because in here OP adds possibility of overloading methods, and author of posted one doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper duck type check is "can your `xxx` be invoked with a specific signature, and its return value used in a certain context".  Having an overloaded `xxx` is not useful, because it matters how it is used.

We start with `can_apply`

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:
    std::true_type{};
}

template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;
```

which tells you if given arguments can be legally passed to some template.

We then express the duck type we want:

```
template<class T>
using xxx_result = decltype( std::declval<T>().xxx() );

template<class T>
using can_xxx = can_apply< xxx_result, T >;
```

and `can_xxx<T>` is truthy or falsy depending on if we can do a `t.xxx()` or not.

If we want a type restriction, we just:

```
template<class T, class R>
using xxx_result_as_R = decltype( R(std::declval<T>().xxx()) );
template<class T, class R>
using can_xxx_as_R = can_apply< xxx_result_as_R, T, R >;
```

so if you want `xxx` to return something `int`-able, we get:

```
template<class T>
using valid_xxx = can_xxx_as_R<T, int>;
```

Comment: Note: `can_apply` is nearly [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Comment: How can you account for the member function being private? This would help with CRTP stuff.

Comment: @rl-s I don't understand the question.  What do you want it to do if `.xxx()` is private?  What do you think it does?

Answer (score 6):

If all you're doing is checking if the *name* `xxx` exists within type `T`, then we can have the following approach that works for all non-`final`/`union` types `T`. We can create a new type that inherits publicly from both `T` and a fallback type that has a member `xxx`. We can access `xxx` unambiguously on the derived type if and only if `T` didn't have the member to begin with.

```
template <class T>
class has_xxx_impl
{
private:
    struct Fallback {
        int xxx;
    };

    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };

    template <class U>
    static std::false_type test(decltype(&U::xxx)* );
    template <class U>
    static std::true_type test(...);
public:
    using type = decltype(test<Derived>(nullptr));
};

template <class T>
struct has_xxx : has_xxx_impl<T>::type
{ };
```

If you want to check for more specific things - like for a `T`, you can call `T{}.xxx()`, I would do it differently.

Comment: That's really clever, triggering a failure when the member *does* exist...

Comment: Since the last test in OP's code if about attribute `xxx` which is not a member function, I do not think that this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Holt Once you know the name exists, it's not much more effort to ensure that its type is a function type.

Comment: @Holt Added that extra bit.

Comment: Also need a caveat about unions too. And you hit the "overloaded function" case if `T::xxx` is inaccessible.

Comment: @T.C. Well that sucks.

Comment: Also, 1) you need to remove pointer for static member functions, and I don't see the point of remove_cv there; 2) this treats all members that you can't take the address of as "overloaded functions": enumerators, bit-fields, types.

Comment: @T.C. Just going to revert to what I had originally, which at least is definitely right for non-class/union types.